# Xamarin Forms - iOS Editor bottom border line

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add a bottom border in a Xamarin Forms Editor for iOS

```
public class LineEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LineColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LineColor), typeof(Color), typeof(LineEntry), Color.Default);
        
    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LineColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and for the renderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LineEditor), typeof(LineEditorRenderer))]
namespace [...]
{
    public class LineEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        private LineEditor _element;
        private CALayer _bottomBorder;

        private const float BorderWidth = 2.0f;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _element = (LineEditor)Element;
            var textView = this.Control;

            _bottomBorder = new CALayer
            {
                Frame = new CGRect(0.0f, Frame.height - BorderWidth, Frame.Width, 1.0f),
                BorderWidth = BorderWidth,
                BorderColor = _element.LineColor.ToCGColor()
            };

            textView.Layer.AddSublayer(_bottomBorder);
            textView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work at all, i tried to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/tonyedwardspz/82e753fc1934a421095b) but without success.

Comment: why you don't simply wrap the editor in a StackLayout and add a line at the bottom with a BoxView or a Line shape ?

Comment: @FabriBertani i can do this indeed, but i just wanted to know if a "native" alternative can work.

Comment: For a native approach I strongly recommend you to use [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) and leave custom renderers aside only for situations when you need to change actual behavior of a control, to improve performance.

Comment: `Visual="Material"`?

Comment: You could try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116561/10768653.